# ValueInjecter v3.0 Exception when target type property has no setter

Tags: valueinjecter

we updated our solution to ValueInjecter v3.0 and now we have big problems because in this version an exception is raised if a property has no setter. This is different to Version 2.3.3.
We have a lot of classes where the missing setter is possible, so what can we do beside scanning the whole source code and check every usage of InjectFrom???
Is there any global Setting who avoids the exception when there is no setter?

Greeting
Martin

Answer (score 0):

no, there isn't any global setting for that, but this has been recently fixed,
you can update to the latest version now, and it should work